# custom search api SSL ERROR

Tags: android, google-custom-search

Im trying to use custom search api and im keep getting
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb4bb3a00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:1407743E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert inappropriate fallback (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0xaba30cc5:0x00000000)

on the line:
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( ( conn.getInputStream() ) ) );

this is my URL:
"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" +key+ "&cx=" +cx+ "&q=" +qry+"&fileType="+fileType+"&searchType="+searchType+"&alt=json"

please please I need your help!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this one as url:
"http://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" +key+ "&cx=" +cx+ "&q=" +qry+"&fileType="+fileType+"&searchType="+searchType+"&alt=json"